# PeerJS data connection doesn't work as expected

Tags: peerjs

I am building audio calling app using [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/).

When I use `peer.on('connection', function() { ... })` inside `peer.on('call', function(call) { ... })`, it doesn't work.

I want to be able to do the above so that I can close the audio stream when I receive data from the call initializer.

Why `peer.on('connection', function() { ... }` doesn't work inside `peer.on('call', function(call) { ... }`?

And how can I go about receiving the data from the caller in the receiver?

**NOTE:** I need to receiver the data inside `peer.on('call', function(call) { ... }` so that I can close the audio stream